# XPath to test (grand)child node value equality?

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath, xpath-1.0

XPath version 1

```
<Cinema>
    <directors>
        <director>Morgan Freeman</director>
    </directors>
    <crew>
        <presenter>Morgan Freeman</presenter>
    </crew>
</Cinema>
```

I was just wondering how I could see if the two values of director and presenter are equal. In other words how to do director = presenter but in XPath query version.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//Cinema[directors/director = crew/presenter]
```

will select all `Cinema` elements that have `directors/director` and `crew/presenter` grandchild elements with the same string values.  Wrap the expression in `boolean()` if you're looking instead for an existence answer.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that it works great, just one last thing. If i had two tables and one had two directors how could i display the one with just the one director?

Comment: Please ask a new question with specific XML and clearly stated conditions for the node(s) that you wish to select.  Thanks.